# An exercise on cyclic extensions of Hungerford's book, Algebra.

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory

I'm trying to show the following exercise of the book, it is in the section of cyclic extensions and says the following:

> Let $\overline{\mathbb Q}$ be a fixed algebraic closure of $\mathbb Q$, let $v\in\overline{\mathbb Q}-\mathbb Q$ and let $E\subseteq\overline{\mathbb Q}$ be a subfield maximal with respect to the property $v\notin E$. Prove that every finite dimensional extension of $E$ is cyclic.

Well, this is my attempt of proof:

First I prove that one can restrict himself to a finite Galois extensions. Then I prove that $E(v)$ is a Galois extension of $E$, by noting that for every $\sigma\in Aut_E E(v)$, $\sigma(v)\notin E$; and that $E(v)$ is a cyclic extension of $E$, because the absence of intermediate fields and applying the fundamental theorem of Galois theory . Next, I intend to proceed inductively in $n=[F:E]$ with the case $n=1$ being trivial:

suppose that the proposition is true for every $m\leq r$, and that $r+1=[F:E]$; consider the intermediate field $E\subseteq E(v)\subseteq F$, if $E(v)=F$ the proposition has already been proven. If not then $[F:E(v)]\leq r$, and we have that $F$ is Galois over $E(v)$ (fundamental theorem), therefore the induction hypothesis shows that $Aut_{E(v)}F$ is cyclic. The fact that $E(v)$ is Galois over $E$ implies that $Aut_{E(v)}F$ is normal in $Aut_E F$ and again by the fundamental theorem $Aut_E E(v)=Aut_E F/Aut_{E(v)}F$.

At this point I had been thinking about a proposition of the form "If a finite group G contains a normal cyclic subgroup such that the quotient $G/N$ is also cyclic then G is cyclic"; which is false, even if one replace normal cyclic, for maximal normal cyclic, and things like this.

I don't know what to do at this stage, I would be very grateful for a solution that follows this path. Thanks in advance.

Comment: " $\,E(v)\,$ is a cyclic extension of $\,E\,$ because the abscence of intermediate fields..." ? How is this? Unless you prove that the extension's degree is a *prime* that claim is false.

Comment: @DonAntonio Yes, Perhaps I could be more explicit here, remember the Galois correspondence, every subgroup of the Galois group corresponds to an intermediate field. In other words there is no non-trivial subgroups in the Galois Group, that implies immediately that this group is cyclic of prime order or the trivial group, but this is not the case.

Comment: I know that @Daniel, yet I still can't see how you think you got this: that $\,\sigma(v)\notin E\;\;\forall\,1\neq\sigma \in\, Aut_E(E(v))\;$ is trivially true *always*, so you must show, imo, what's different in this case.

Comment: @DonAntonio Here, I'm not trying to show completely the proof, I'm only sketching it. But suppose that $\sigma\in Aut_E E(v)$ and $\sigma\neq 1$ then $\sigma(v)\neq v$ (all $E$-automorphisms of $E(v)$ are completely characterized by their action on $v$), now take the fixed field of $\sigma$, $L=\{x\in E(v): \sigma(x)=x\}$, then $L$ is a proper subfield of the extension, contradicting the maximality of $E$.

Comment: Is there any reason to think that $E(v)$ has non-trivial $E$-automorphisms? If not, then you may be stuck with $L=E(v)$ not being a proper subfield of $E(v)$ in your previous comment.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Well, if there exists an unique $E$-automorphism de $E(v)$ ($\sigma=1$) the the Galois group is trivial, and cyclic. For this reason I said "$\sigma\neq 1$."

Comment: An extension of fields $F/E$ is called cyclic, iff A) it is a Galois extension and B) the Galois group is cyclic. For example $\mathbb{Q}(\root 3\of 2)$ is not a cyclic extension of $\mathbb{Q}$ simply because it has no non-trivial automorphisms.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Ok now I understand you, I can't say that is there is no other $E$-automorphism different to the identity.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hints:

1. Let $F$ be any finite extension of $E$. Show that $F/E$ is separable, simple and that there exists an extension field $M/E$ such that $F\subseteq M$, and $M/E$ is a finite Galois extension.
2. Show that $H=\operatorname{Gal}(M/E(v))$ is the unique maximal subgroup of $G=\operatorname{Gal}(M/E)$.
3. Show that any element $\sigma\in G\setminus H$ generates $G$.
4. Show that $F/E$ is cyclic.

Comment: Nice answer, in fact I think the degree of $F/E$ has to be a prime power.

Comment: Nice, I didn't note that $H$ was the unique maximal subgroup of $G$. Thank you!!!

Comment: Well done, Daniel!

Comment: could you kindly explain me why element of G\H generates G and why F/E is cyclic...@JyrkiLahtonen

Comment: @sayak: Let $\sigma\in G$. Unless $\sigma$ generates all of $G$ it belongs to some maximal proper subgroup $K$ of $G$. But in step 2 we proved that $H$ is the only maximal proper subgroup of $G$. So if $\sigma$ does not generate $G$, then we must have $\sigma\in H$.