# Prove that $G$ is a cyclic group whose order is a prime power.

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory

Let $K$ be a finite Galois extension of $F$ with Galois group $G=Gal(K/F)$. Assume that there exists an intermediate field $E\neq F$ between $K$ and $F$ so that for any such intermediate filed $E'\neq F$ we have $E\subset E'$. Prove that $G$ is a cyclic group whose order is a prime power.

---

We know that every field extension $K/E'$ is Galois because $K/F$ is Galois. But I am stuck here...I do not know why can we say the order is prime power.

Any answer will be appreciate.

Comment: Try to convert this into a problem about groups. This is the main idea of Galois theory, the ability to turn difficult problems about fields into more simple problems about groups. What can you say about $\text{Gal}(K/F)$?

Comment: @Mark By Galois theory, "there exists an intermediate field $E\subset E'$" means the corresponding Galois group "$Gal(K/E')\subset Gal(K/E)$ for any $E\subset E'$". But we do not know the order of $Gal(K/F)$ prime or not... So how do I apply result from $p$-group?

Comment: Mark nailed it (as was expected). In case you have trouble with the group theoretic part, I used a similar argument [in this oldie](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/365265/11619).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** By the fundamental theorem of Galois theory it follows almost immediately that $\text{Gal}(K/F)$ has a unique maximal subgroup. It is a very standard exercise that a finite group with a unique maximal subgroup must be cyclic, that was already proved on this forum before.

It is also easy to verify that a cyclic group with a unique maximal subgroup must be a $p$-group.